# how to convert windows 7 home edition to windows 7 professional

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Upgrading from Windows 7 Home Premium to Professional](https://superuser.com/questions/187666/upgrading-from-windows-7-home-premium-to-professional)
>   [Upgrading Windows 7 Home Premium to Professional](https://superuser.com/questions/221022/upgrading-windows-7-home-premium-to-professional)

I have bought a new laptop. This laptop's OS windows 7 home edition x64
I have a msdn account and it provides me windows 7 professional x64 key.
Now, How to convert windows 7 home edition to windows 7 professional ?

Thanks for everything.

Comment: While this might be a duplicate, the question you linked to is worthless because it too has no answers to the question of upgrading or converting a lower edition of windows to a higher edition of windows.

Comment: @Chris - it does now; and just because it doesn't (didn't) have any answers doesn't mean it's not a duplicate question.

Comment: I'm sure that Thomas G will appreciate the answer since he asked it back on asked Sep 12, 2010 at 9:26 and didn't get an answer until just now.

Comment: Actually this question is even closer: [Upgrading Windows 7 Home Premium to Professional](http://superuser.com/questions/221022/upgrading-windows-7-home-premium-to-professional) due to it also discussing using an MSDN key.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in ealier question you can use the Anytime upgrade in most cases but not sure on the MSDN key.

[Anytime Upgrade](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows7/help/videos/upgrade-to-another-edition-of-windows-7-by-using-windows-anytime-upgrade)

Comment: MSDN should have provided you with a key conveying the license. Simply use this key in the Anytime Upgrade process.

Answer (score 0):

I used the instructions posted at this article to convert a Windows 7 x86 Professional Edition iso image to Windows 7 x64 Professional. Its a simple process of editing one file (ei.cfg) through a script which makes the image an "universal disc" that will prompt the user to select an edition during setup, which can also be reversed to go back to the previous iso state if needed.  Its a simple process of editing one file (ei.cfg) through a script, which can also be reversed to go back to the previous iso state if needed.

http://code.kliu.org/misc/winisoutils/